# About assigning values to functions

Tags: c++, assign, rvalue

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class X {
int i;
public:
    X(int ii = 0);
    void modify();
};

X::X(int ii) { i = ii; }
void X::modify() { i++; }

X f5() {   return X(); }
const X f6() {   return X(); }

void f7(X& x) {
  x.modify();
}

int f()
{
    return 18;
}
int main() {
  f5() = X(1);          /// Why does this work??? Isn't f5() an rvalue ??? (*)
  f5().modify();
///  f7(f5());          /// cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'X&' to an rvalue of type X; not contradictory with (*)?
//!  f6() = X(1);
//!  f6().modify();
//!  f7(f6());
//! f() = 12; this also doesn't work
  return 0;
}
```

How can `f5() = X()` work ? Isn't f5() a rvalue ? Then why doesn't `f() = 12` work ? What is the difference ? Also, the error that `f7(f5())` generates doesn't say that `f5()` is a rvalue ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

`f5()` indeed yields an rvalue and `f5() = X(1);` invokes implicitly generated move `operator =`. It will stop working if this operator is deleted: `void operator =(X &&) = delete;`.

Also the error that f7(f5()) generates does say that `f5()` is an rvalue:

> to an rvalue of type X

Comment: But what is the difference between that and ```f() = 12``` ?

Comment: The difference is that `f()` yeilds a built-in primitive `int` type. Assignment to such a type requires left operand to be an lvalue.

Comment: To be clear, deleting the move assignment prevents this, but it also prevents other things from working. To disable specifically this behavior, you `&`-qualify copy and move assignments.